# How to get the 3rd h1 value in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have the following codes below:

```
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="inner">
     <h1 _ngcontent-c6=""> Testing 1 </h1>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="inner">
     <h1 _ngcontent-c6=""> Testing 2 </h1>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="inner">
     <h1 _ngcontent-c6=""> Testing 3 </h1>
</div>
```

I wish to get the value of the 3rd h1.  So I tried element(by.css("h1")).getText();  But what I'm getting is the 1st value.  How can I get the 3rd value then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Protractor's **[`.get()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get)**, which takes an index:

```
element.all(By.tagName('h1')).get(2).getText();
```

Or the CSS pseudo-class **[`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)**:

```
element(By.css('h1:nth-of-type(2)').getText();
```

Comment: using `nth-of-type` it should be `element(By.css('h1:nth-of-type(3)').getText();` Indexing starts with `1`.